# Tags Without Wiki

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

As a newcomer to this site, I have noticed that there is a much higher proportion of tags that have no wiki compared to other sites on Stack Exchange.  Many of these tags seem to be film titles - but not all.

Given that wiki-less tags can be auto-deleted if they are not widely used, should we be actively encouraging people to create some wikis?

Comment: First of all, sure, if you got the time and mood, adding Wikis to those things is a good idea, encouraging other users to do so is too. But are you sure about that rule of tags without a Wiki getting deleted? Also keep in mind that our site employs some special rules regarding tag deletion, for example tags with a single question won't get deleted here, this is exactly because of the policy to have a tag for each movie title.

Comment: Related: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/897/49.

Comment: I had assumed wikiless one-question tags would be deleted from my experience elsewhere.  Keeping them on this site seems a good thing.  I wouldn't wish to flood the Suggested Edits queue with additions as I know how much review time that can take.  The second paragraph of the accepted answer to the related post is pertinent to this question.

Comment: @Chenmunka i don't mind in checking too many review summits but remember too many rejection can block a user, doesn't remember the exact scenario, may be its automatic of mod approved.

Comment: Anyways review bar is a win-win situation, submitter get rep and approval person might get badge and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag on site like movies and TV are too many as compare to other sites because of large number of movies and TV shows (with addition of director/production tags). **Deleting tag because they don't have wikis seems too unfair.**

Solution can be-

- Submitting tag wikis for tags on basics of popularity, so that important one will fix soon.
- Removing one time used unnecessary tags, then they will be auto-delete soon. But remember movie name and TV show name tag doesn't considered unnecessary.

But this can be be a long task and high rep user like me can directly submit tag wikis but low rep user submitted tag wikis wait for peer approval. And in tag wikis we also need to take care about copyright contents too.

Comment: I don't even think that rule about deleting un-Wikid tags is used on this site at all. I've posted some questions about obscure movies that don't have a Wiki or another question at all, and they never got deleted. I guess this is part of the general rule of deleting 1-question tags, which our site does explicitly not use.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson i also thinks the same and i though there was some meta post over it but enable to find it.

Comment: Ooops you already mentioned that in comment